# Why is BindingRedirect not being applied

Tags: c#, .net

I have a binding redirect which works on one machine, but not another.

I have used fuslogvw to view this log and this is what it says:

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Dev/PropertySearch/PropertySearch/PropertySearch.Tests/bin/x86/Debug/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Dev\PropertySearch\PropertySearch\PropertySearch.Tests\bin\x86\Debug\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
```

This is what the binding redirect looks like:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.1.0" newVersion="4.121.1.0" />
```

As far as I can tell, everything matches up correctly.

This is the error that is generated at runtime:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.112.3.60, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.112.3.60, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"}
```

Can anyone see what is going on?

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is working in one machine and not in another the only reason is that the new assembly is not installed in the GAC in the failing computer.